# Prevent footer from overlapping combining with float

Tags: html, css, css-float, footer

I have created a bubble conversation html. 
Now I am trying to add a footer to it.
(Footer similar code in https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_fixed_footer)

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  width: 80%;
  background: #eee;
}

.him {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.me {
  float: right;
}

#footer {
  height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="me">N-19</li>
      <li class="me">N-18</li>
      <li class="him">N-17</li>
      <li class="me">N-16</li>
      <li class="me">N-15</li>
      <li class="me">N-14</li>
      <li class="him">N-13</li>
      <li class="me">N-12</li>
      <li class="me">N-11</li>
      <li class="me">N-10</li>
      <li class="me">N-9</li>
      <li class="me">N-8</li>
      <li class="him">N-7</li>
      <li class="me">N-6</li>
      <li class="me">N-5</li>
      <li class="me">N-4</li>
      <li class="me">N-3</li>
      <li class="me">N-2</li>
      <li class="me">N-1</li>
      <li class="him">N</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

But I am not seeing the last lines of the conversation. The problem is that the footer is overlaping them because of the float property of the < li > elements.

[image]

How can I avoid it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58191649/8138584

Comment: i have just shared the solution you wanted. if you want optimized solution i can give you that .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this out: `css grid` is a very good property of `css`.
we can divide screen into number of columns and rows . i used here css-grid.

for more info on css-grid read
 https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

```css
ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display:grid;
      grid-template-columns:33% 33% 34%;
  
    }

    ul li {
      display: block;
      clear: both;
      padding: 5px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
      
      background: #eee;
    }

    .him {
      grid-column:1/3;
      border: 1px solid #000000;
    }

    .me {
    grid-column:2/4
      
    }

    #footer {
      height: 30px;
      position: fixed;
      bottom:0;
      
      width: 100%;
      background-color: red;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }

    body {
      padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li class="me">N-19</li>
          <li class="me">N-18</li>
          <li class="him">N-17</li>
          <li class="me">N-16</li>
          <li class="me">N-15</li>
          <li class="me">N-14</li>
          <li class="him">N-13</li>
          <li class="me">N-12</li>
          <li class="me">N-11</li>
          <li class="me">N-10</li>
          <li class="me">N-9</li>
          <li class="me">N-8</li>
          <li class="him">N-7</li>
          <li class="me">N-6</li>
          <li class="me">N-5</li>
          <li class="me">N-4</li>
          <li class="me">N-3</li>
          <li class="me">N-2</li>
          <li class="me">N-1</li>
          <li class="him">N</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
        Footer
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How about a more thorough explanation than "check this out"?

Comment: The footer is working but now the "me" bubbles have white space to their right. They are not stuck to the right margin

Comment: float on the .me and .him elements is what seems to be causing the body {padding-bottom: 30px} to not apply as expected. using a different layout method would remove that issue.

Comment: @Cathy i think he asked that how to make fixed footer if you see first para. we are not closing the issue but giving  alternate solution so at least for now he can decide what is best for him. what to choose.

Comment: @Alfonso_MA can you clear that you want solution without removing float or you need  a optimized approach to get the resulted output/

Comment: @NaveenJain I don't need the float property strictly. But I need to mantain the visual effect of conversation. Seems like .him {grid-column:1/4;width:75%;} and  .me {grid-column:2/4} did the trick. If you upload the answer I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: @Alfonso_MA update code so width is ok  now. css-grid i have divided screen into 3 column  (33% 33% 34%).  for him class i given first 2 column, and me class i given last 2 clolumns. you can change this divide ratio as you want . even in px

Answer (score 0):

Due to `padding-bottom` could not be applied here, my answer didn't fit in the case, therefore I've done a research on the alternatives for a grid layout proposed and, surprisingly, for the `fixed` positioning of the footer block.

In this example I've decided to leave the code without the `<ul>` which has quite a big list of [default element css values](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp). I supposed that the first message always comes from the user, and used `:not()` CSS selector to style the replies blocks. You can change `.user` and `:not(user)` to any classes like `.me` and `.him` according to your HTML.

```css
section {display:flex;flex-direction:column}

section * {
  width: 75%;
  border: 1px solid #757575;
  border-radius:20px;
  padding:2px 10px;
  margin-bottom:2px
}

.user {
  background:#ccc;
  margin-left: auto
}

section :not(.user) {
  background:#eee
}

section :not(.user) + .user, .user + :not(.user) {
  margin-top:5px
} 

footer { 
  height: 30px;
  position: sticky; /* Yes. It works now */
  bottom: 0;
  background: #000;
  color: white;
  text-align: center; 
  line-height: 28px
}
```

```html
<section>
      <div class="user">Need some help with HTML</div>
      <div class="user">And CSS maybe</div>
      <div class="user">Want it to work with long-lenth messages as well, you know. And in all the browsers, even IE...</div>
      <div>Sure</div>
      <div>Lets test this one</div>
      <div>Quite a good in terms of browser support in 2019</div>
      <div class="user">Awsome!</div>
      <div class="user">Thank you so much</div>
      <div>You are welcome</div>
      <div class="user">Goodbye</div>
</section>

<footer>
<p>Sticky Footer</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Or just add the padding-bottom on the ul itself

Comment: @Cathy if the HTML part of the page is generated automatically - CSS would still be the best solution

Comment: I meant by adding CSS but instead of on the :last-child just add it to the ul itself. It could also be put on the body tag in case the content changes. @Senpai.D

Comment: @Cathy sorry, thought you've meant the last li inline styling  that's an option as well

Comment: as a side note - it is the float on the .me and .him items that is making the body's padding-bottom not work. using a different way to layout the list, perhapse like the grid solution presented by@Naveen Jain, would remove that issue.